# The column state is not remembered

Tags: yadcf

Good day.

I'm using datatables with the yadcf plugin. The data is server side. When enabling state to true, the column selections are not remembered.

My table settings:

```
let table = $('#data-table').DataTable({
        // NOTE: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/61967/duplicate-the-showing-1-to-10-of-xx-entries-to-top-of-the-table
        // set DOM to also place info (i) at top; i=info, f=dropdown pagefilter, l=search, p=pagination
        "dom": 'B<"top"ifl<"clear">>rt<"bottom"ip<"clear">>',
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: 'trademark/data-source',
        order: [[2, 'asc']],
        stateSave: true,
        footerCallback: function () {
            $('#data-table tfoot').remove();
        },
        lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100, 500, 1000], [10, 25, 50, 100, 500, 1000]],
        displayLength: 10,
        select: true,
        ...

    // Initialise data filter
    yadcf.init(table, [
            { column_number : 3, html_data_type: "text", sort_as: "alphaNum", filter_reset_button_text: false, filter_type: "multi_select", select_type: 'select2' },
            { column_number : 4, html_data_type: "text", sort_as: "alphaNum", filter_reset_button_text: false, filter_type: "multi_select", select_type: 'select2' }
...
        ]
    );
```

Regards,
Jarrett

Followed the instructions at https://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_Ajax_Multiple_1.10.html. But even that example does not have state working.